# Android - db query not sorting well?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I have a problem with my query

```
public ArrayList<String> getUniqueYears(String TABLE_NAME) {

      ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
      final String[] cat = new String[] {KEY_YEAR};

      Cursor cursor = myDatabase.query(true, TABLE_NAME, cat, null, null, null, null, KEY_YEAR, null);


              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {

                      content.add(cursor.getString(0));
                 } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }

      cursor.close();
      return content;
}
```

when i call the function returns me this:

[111, 1111, 124, 1242, 1345, 1943, 2345, 345]

thank's

Comment: that's alphabetical sort. post you database creation.

Comment: you could use the cast function in your order by clause => `"CAST(" + KEY_YEAR + " as SIGNED)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently sorting by `KEY_YEAR` as if those where strings:

1. 111 before 1111, because `111` and `111`1 are equal, but the second one has an extra character, thus i is "numerically greater" than the first one.
2. 1111 before 124, because `1`111 and `1`24 are equal, but 1`1`11 is "numerically lower" than 1`2`4. The rest is not used for sorting this pair

And so and so....

How are you storing `KEY_YEAR`? It should be a `NUMBER`

Comment: yes, i'm putting a String into the DB... should be a number. Thank's